# NSTableView selected row flickering while scrolling with arrow keys

Tags: xcode, macos, nstableview, appkit

I have a view based NSTableView and can't figure out how to work around a visual glitch where the currently selected row flickers while scrolling up or down with the arrow keys.

[image]

The selected row should appear 'glued' to either the top or bottom of the view, depending on scroll direction. The Finder shows this correct behavior in list view but a regular table view seems to not behave this way out of the box. I'm confused as to why that is and see no obvious way to circumvent it. Can anybody point me to possible causes / solutions?

**Edit No. 1**

A cell based NSTableView behaves in the desired way by default, so this is presumably a bug specific to the view based implementation. I don't want to use a cell based table for unrelated reasons though.

**Edit No. 2**

I've tried making the table view's parent view layer backed, as well as intercepting the up / down arrow keystrokes to do my own scrolling, but so far I haven't been able to eliminate the flickering.

**Edit No. 3**

I've created a small [sample project](https://github.com/tesch/nstableview-scrolling-glitch) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: It would really help if you gave us a minimal app that does reproduce the problem. Put it in GitHub and give us a link to it.

Comment: @jvarela I added a sample project that shows the problem.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your bug. Actually even my own table code shows that bug too, which I had never noticed. I even checked in Apple's sample code and they have the same problem. Perhaps the only way to solve the problem would be to customize the way the selection is drawn. I tried to customize this drawing by overriding NSTableRowView drawSelection(in:) but using NSRect fill() method results in the same flickering. Perhaps you should open a DTS incident and ask Apple how to solve this bug.

Comment: The bug can be found in various third party and even some system apps as well. Inspecting a Finder window in the view debugger shows that it's using a view based outline view, so given the fact that the flickering doesn't occur there shows that it must be possible to work around it somehow. I don't have a developer account, so unfortunately I won't be able to open a DTS incident about it.

Comment: Out of interest, would someone be able to test the sample project on Big Sur? Maybe this got (inadvertently) fixed as a result of the UI rework.

Comment: It flickers on Big Sur as well (beta 3).

Comment: @zrzka Thanks, that's what I feared. Doesn't look like there is a straightforward solution to this.

Comment: It looks like the selection changes and the old and new selected rows are redrawn. Next the selected row is animated up/down. Disabling scroll animation fixes the issue.

Comment: @Willeke Could you elaborate on how to do that? If you want to write up a short answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the selection changes and the old and new selected rows are redrawn. Next the selected row is animated up/down. Disabling scroll animation fixes the issue. Scroll animation can be disabled by subclassing `NSClipView` and overriding `scroll(to:)`.

```
override func scroll(to newOrigin: NSPoint) {
    setBoundsOrigin(newOrigin)      
}
```

It might have some side effects.

**Edit**

Copied from zrzka's solution, with some adjustments. Scroll animation is temporarily disabled when using the up arrow or down arrow key.

```
class TableView: NSTableView {

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if let clipView = enclosingScrollView?.contentView as? ClipView,
            (125...126).contains(event.keyCode) && // down arrow and up arrow
            event.modifierFlags.intersection([.option, .shift]).isEmpty {
            clipView.isScrollAnimationEnabled = false
            super.keyDown(with: event)
            clipView.isScrollAnimationEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            super.keyDown(with: event)
        }
    }
    
}

class ClipView: NSClipView {

    var isScrollAnimationEnabled: Bool = true
    
    override func scroll(to newOrigin: NSPoint) {
        if isScrollAnimationEnabled {
            super.scroll(to: newOrigin)
        } else {
            setBoundsOrigin(newOrigin)
            documentView?.enclosingScrollView?.flashScrollers()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: One is that the Home / End key scrolling is not animated (if you don't have a full keyboard it's the same as Fn + Left Arrow / Fn + Right Arrow).

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! Maybe this answer can be build upon to allow for home / end to still be animated, but I'm happy to use it as is.

Comment: Just FYI - I spent my TSI (Technical Support Incident) on this. I was just curious what Apple folks recommends/thinks. DTS gave me back my TSI and told me to submit a bug report. Did it (FB8249979).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try change the view ?

```
scrollView.wantsLayer = true
```

If you used Interface Builder:

Select the scroll view
Open the View Effects Inspector (or press Cmd-Opt-8)
In the table, find the row for your scroll view and check the box.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Doesn't make any discernible difference, still flickers.